# How to remove extra line in mail body on using action "Send an email notification (V3)"?

Tags: flow, microsoft

Extra line comes in mail body on using action "Send an email notification (V3)"

Extra line is **"If you want to unsubscribe from these emails, please use this form."**

How can remove this extra line from mail message

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the extra line at the end of the "Send an email notification" Flow action simply add the following piece of HTML at the end of your email body:

```
<div style="display:none !important">
// This area hides the unwanted message at the end of your email
```

**Explanation**:

We create a div tag, but don't close it. It means all content that is added after this div tag is considered a child content and the `style="display:none !important"` will hide the div itself and all its child contents.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: <div style="display:none;"> is not working for me. I am using table tag in my mail. May be that is a issue

Comment: it should work. Remove the ; and add !important. See if it helps.